# Highlight single row in a table

Tags: tables

I am trying to highlight the last row in my table.

I have tried other solutions, but these solutions to highlight a single row in my table result in this error:

> Undefined control sequence.  \rowcolor

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Method} & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Sensitivity} & \textbf{Specificity} \\
\midrule
Sobel & 0.49\% & 0.20\% & 0.87\%  \\
Canny & 0.49\% & 0.17\% & 0.91\% \\ 
LoG & 0.49\% & 0.17\% & 0.92\%  \\ 
Sobel RGB Extraction  & 0.50\% & 0.15\% & 0.96\% \\ 
Canny RGB Extraction  & 0.55\% & 0.54\% & 0.57\% \\ 
LoG RGB Extraction  & 0.56\% & 0.36\% & 0.84\% \\ 
K-Means  & 0.37\% & 0.42\% & 0.29\% \\ 
Fuzzy C-Means & 0.41\% & 0.44 \% & 0.31 \% \\ 
Otsu's Method & 0.39\% & 0.45\% & 0.32\% \\ 
Local Otsu's Method & 0.49\% & 0.45\% & 0.54\% \\ 
Histogram Thresholding & 0.64\% & 0.52\% & 0.60\%  \\ 
\rowcolor{lightgray} Proposed Method & 0.66\% & 0.64\% & 0.69\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Performance of segmentation techniques on the dataset.}
\end{center}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you load `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`?

Comment: Thanks! It works!